# Hazelcast configuration for an AWS hybrid cloud environment

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, hazelcast

I'm using Hazelcast for a project at my university.
The objective is to use Hazelcast to connect a local datacenter with AWS.
54.76.224.90 is the public IP-Adress of my Windows EC2-Server, I deactivated the firewall and added the ports 5781-5785 to the security group.
However, I cannot connect a hazelcast instance from my local computer with the EC2-Server and I end up having two separate cluster.
Here is the configuration:

```
    Config cfg = new Config();
    cfg.setProperty("hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size","2");

    NetworkConfig ncfg = cfg.getNetworkConfig();
    ncfg.setPort(5781);
    ncfg.setPortAutoIncrement(true);
    ncfg.getInterfaces().setEnabled(true).addInterface("*.*.*.*");

    JoinConfig jcfg = ncfg.getJoin();
    jcfg.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);

    jcfg.getTcpIpConfig().
    addMember("54.76.224.90").
    setRequiredMember(null).
    setEnabled(true).
    setConnectionTimeoutSeconds(20);
```

Comment: Is the instance inside any VPC ? Check the PORT, PROTOCOL, IP all the 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the line, where the interface is defined, completely. The problem was that the interface was wrong. Apparently the interface `"*.*.*.*"` doesn't allow any connection at all.